# c# winforms datagridview databinding

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I must be missing something really obvious but I have narrowed down the problem to the simplest possible repro case.

I am trying to debug an old Winforms 2.0 app that has no docs and was written, well a long time ago. I am using VS 2012.

I have a SQLCE 4.0 DB with 4 small tables in it. I created a DataSet by adding the DB to the DataSources window.

I then added a bindingSource and DataGridView to the form bound them together and pointed them at the DataSource and they added a strongly typed DataSet.

If I manually enter the data into the SDF using Server Explorer and then run the app I see all the data in the grid.

BUT if I enter data into the grid, one row or many it does not get committed to the DB.

If I do all this in code and don't use any of the autogenerated stuff I can get it to work but the existing app uses all the autogenerated stuff and I don't feel like going back and fixing 20+ grids by hand if this is the only pattern I can get to work.

I feel like I must be missing something really simple that writes are not getting through to the DB, but I can't find it.

Thx

Comment: Is there any code you can share with us?

Comment: The simplest solution for you is `Debug`. Only it can help you in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this .. In VB

When you have this ..

```
Private bindingSource1 As New BindingSource()
Private dataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
Dim table As New DataTable()
```

And doing this

```
Me.dataAdapter.Fill(table)
Me.bindingSource1.DataSource = table
```

Then user made some changes in your bindingsource then don't forget

```
Me.dataAdapter.Update(CType(Me.bindingSource1.DataSource, DataTable))
```

Comment: matzone, yeah I have something like that working in my other repro case so I know I can get it to work in code.

Comment: Avi, for the case I am trying to fix there is not a line of code written, its using purely the autogen stuff.